# How to use flask-SQLalchemy LIKE and OR operators in single query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

1. My goal is : convert raw query into SQLalchemy ORM query
2. raw query:

```
Select * from log where log.page != null and (log.page LIKE "%page_1%" or LIKE "%page_2%" or LIKE "%page_3%");
```

3. my code:

```
from models import Log
selected_page = ["page_1", "page_2", "page_3"...]
like_query = []
for pages in selected_page:
        like_tag = "%{}%".format(pages)
        like_query.append(or_(Log.page.like(like_tag)))
db.session.query(Log).filter(Log.page is not null).filter(*like_query);
```

4. Error response:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object expected, got object of type <class 'list'> instead
```

Comment: i think you should run a for loop and replace like_query with like_query[i] where i is the index of the elements present in the like_query.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Is `log.page LIKE "%page_1%" or LIKE "%page_2%"` actually valid in that? And does what you expect? `Log.page is not null` is definitely not doing what you'd expect; `is [ not ]` is object identity comparison that happens *in Python*. For the error, please provide the full traceback.